# setting appearance of radiobutton as textarea in codename one

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I am building an app using [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

I have a radiobutton with a very long text.

When i focus on this radio button , the text of that radio button starts scrolling.

What I wish to do is show all the text associated with the radiobutton on the screen.

So i tried `radiotbutton.setUIID("TextArea");`

But with this, only the appearance of the radiobutton changes. THe radio button's text does not spill over to multiple lines.

I want to show the radio button's text all at once (no matter how long it is) . How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiButton` has a radio button mode but you need to know the number of lines in advance.

The solution to this is something like:

```
RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(new BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
c.addComponent(r);
TextArea radioText = new TextArea("Long text for radio button");
radioText.setEditable(false);
c.addComponent(radioText);
radioText.setUIID("RadioButton");
c.setLeadComponent(r);
```

You can do this entire thing in the GUI builder which supports lead component as well.